# How to use mapview showsUserLocation and not focus into it on react native?

Tags: javascript, ios, dictionary, react-native

I am using showsUserLocation, there is an animation zooming in the location position, how to not zoom into it

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well, and had a look at the source code. It looks like by default if showsUserLocation is set the map is forced to follow it, however I managed to disable that by commenting out line 92 of node_modules/react-native/React/Views/RCTMap.m so that;

`_followUserLocation = showsUserLocation;`

becomes

`//_followUserLocation = showsUserLocation;`

Note that this will disable that autozoom to your location on all maps.